# Can ice jam in river destroy a stone bridge?

Tags: bridges

In a fiction story I am currently writing, I have this situation.

It's early spring, and a river in a mountainous region has just broken up the ice, and moves it downstream. Naturally, ice jams are forming along the way.

Two characters, the main one and another, ride into a nature park, crossing a bridge over a canal connecting the river with ponds designed to relieve the river of excess water during this period of the year, thus protecting the city downstream from floods.

When they ride back, ice jams destroy the bridge before their eyes.

**The question** is, would this be possible if the bridge were built of stone? If generally not, are there circumstances under which it might happen?

If a stone bridge can't be destroyed in this fashion under no circumstance, what material could this bridge have been built that could survive almost all cases until this situation?

Comment: This is something you could research - lots of news about snow, ice and bridges exist.

Comment: You are trying to attribute something to "ice jams" and things happen for every reason that there is, so as long as the overall circumstances dictate that something happens and "ice jams" exist, then it is not inherently wrong to blame "ice jams" as you can blame butterflies for tornadoes. Envision the circumstances- which direction does the bridge break and why? Where is the energy coming from for the bonds in the bridge to come undone? Why does it happen when it happens, rather than an hour or so prior or later?

Comment: @Abel What do you mean by putting ice jams in quotation marks and comparing them to butterflies and tornadoes?

Comment: You can replace ice jams with just about anything. World building and story telling have very loose requirements, and every second reality has more coincidences than any storyteller will ever be able to write about, simply due to the vastness of existence. Ever hear of the butterfly effect?